# Where to store response from server in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I do GET request to server that to get JSON data as:

```
{
name: 'http://placehold.it/32x32',
age: '20',
social: {
  id: '1',
  count: '3',
  shares: '3'
}
}
```

What is the best way to store this data in variable that after show it in TableView?
Should I create `@property` for each JSON key?
Or create one object as `NSDictionary`?

Comment: the first one, create a CustomClass (or struct) with properties for name, age and social (which might itself be another class or struct)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class/struct with these properties at the earliest.
Something like this:

**SWIFT**

```
class myClass {

    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
    var id: Int?
    var count: Int?
    var shares: Int?

    init(dictionary: [String:AnyObject]) {
        name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        age = dictionary["age"] as? Int

        if let social = dictionary["social"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
            id = social["id"] as? Int
            count = social["count"] as? Int
            shares = social["shares"] as? Int
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you get the data back you can create your object like this.

```
let myObject = myClass(dictionary: jsonDictionary)
```

It's essentially the same for Objective-C:

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger age;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger socialID;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger count;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger shares;

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    if ((self = [self init])) {
        _name = dictionary[@"name"]
        _age = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"age"] integerValue] 

        NSDictionary *social = dictionary[@"social"]
        _socialID = [[social valueForKey:@"id"] integerValue]
        _count = [[social valueForKey:@"count"] integerValue]
        _shares = [[social valueForKey:@"shares"] integerValue]
    }
}
```

Comment: When a question is tagged with a specific language you should post code in that language.